# re pulls data from one tag and not the other

Tags: regex, loops

I am trying to get a program to work that parses html like tags- it's for a TREC collection.  I don't program often, except for databases and I am getting stuck on syntax.  Here's my current code:

```
parseTREC ('LA010189.txt')

#Following Code-re P worked in Python
def parseTREC (atext):
  atext=open(atext, "r")
  filePath= "testLA.txt"
  docID= []
  docTXT=[]
  p = re.compile ('<DOCNO>(.*?)</DOCNO>', re.IGNORECASE)
  m= re.compile ('<P>(.*?)</P>', re.IGNORECASE)
  for aline in atext:
    values=str(aline)
    if p.findall(values):
      docID.append(p.findall(values))
      if m.findall(values):
        docID.append(p.findall(values))
  print docID
  atext.close()
```

the p re pulled the DOCNO as it was supposed. The m re though would not pull data and would print an empty list.  I pretty sure that there are white spaces and also a new line.  I tried the re.M and that did not help pull the data from the other lines.  Ideally I would like to get to the point to where I store in a dictionary {DOCNO, Count}.  Count would be determined by summing up every word that is in the P tags and also in a list [].  I would appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing all the line breaks from the file if you think that is impacting your regex results.  Also, make sure you don't have nested <P> tags because your regex may not match as expected.  For example:

```
<p>
  <p>
    <p>here's some data</p>
    And some more data.
  </p>
  And even more data.
</p>
```

will capture this section because of the "?":

```
  <p>
    <p>here's some data</p>
    And some more data.
```

Also, is this a typo:

```
if p.findall(values):
      docID.append(p.findall(values))
      if m.findall(values):
        docID.append(p.findall(values))
```

should that be:

```
docID.append(m.findall(values))
```

ont the last line?

Comment: Thanks- yep the last line is a typo.  My old programming teacher instructed me to use the code I put in my answer post.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `re.DOTALL` flag like so:

```py
m= re.compile ('<P>(.*?)</P>',
    re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

You may want to add this to the other regex as well.

Comment: The <p> and text are on different lines so the re.DOTALL will not solve my problem.  Thanks though for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

from xml.dom.minidom import *

import re

```
def parseTREC2 (atext):  
    fc = open(atext,'r').read()  
    fc = '<DOCS>\n' + fc + '\n</DOCS>'  
    dom = parseString(fc)  
    w_re = re.compile('[a-z]+',re.IGNORECASE)  
    doc_nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('DOC')  
    for doc_node in doc_nodes:  
        docno = doc_node.getElementsByTagName('DOCNO')[0].firstChild.data  
        cnt = 1  
        for p_node in doc_node.getElementsByTagName('P'):  
            p = p_node.firstChild.data  
            words = w_re.findall(p)  
            print "\t".join([docno,str(cnt),p])  
            print words  
            cnt += 1
```

parseTREC2('LA010189.txt')

## The code adds tags to the front of the document because there is no parent tag.  The program then retrieves the information through the xml parser.